# Check if date is between x and y and if so copy data to new spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a simple application that checks if an application was submitted between date x and date y on spreadsheet "Super Applications Progress" and if it was copy the data to a new spreadsheet "Application".

The current code I have is this:

```
Sub ApplicationSubmitted()

    Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = Worksheets("Super Applications Progress")
    Dim Target As Worksheet: Set Target = Worksheets("Application")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim DateFrom As Date
    Dim DateTo As Date

    DateFrom = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Application").Range("F3")
    DateTo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Application").Range("F5")
    LastRow = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Target.Rows("4:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For i = 4 To LastRow

        If Source.Cells(i, 4) >= DateFrom And Source.Cells(i, 4) <= DateTo Then

            LastRow2 = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1) = Source.Cells(i, 1)
            Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, "B") = Source.Cells(i, "D")
            Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 3) = Source.Cells(i, "F")

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

**The Errors:**

- The Dates entered do bring back a list of clients, however only few clients are shown
- When I click to run the macro again, the date disappears (I know that is to do with `Target.Rows("4:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents` However I am not sure how to limit that for the range F2:F5

The cells I am trying to copy are:

1. Clients Name from Super Applications Progress Column A *to* Application Column A
2. Date Submitted from Super Applications Progress Column D *to* Application Column B
3. Clients Member number from Super Applications Progress Column F *to* Application Column C

Which I've tried to execute using this piece of code:

```
Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1) = Source.Cells(i, 1)

Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, "B") = Source.Cells(i, "D")

Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 3) = Source.Cells(i, "F")
```

I am not sure what the discrepancy is in my code. I am still new to VBA and more than willing to do my own research, just not entirely sure what is causing this error.

Comment: Since you are new to VBA, I will give you a little advice to start your programming career: If possible, avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveCell`, `.Select`, `.Selection`, etc... In this case, a much better alternative of `ActiveWorkbook` would be `ThisWorkbook` (or actually defining the workbook name, such as `Workbooks("...")`.

Comment: Also, not sure why you are using this line: `DateFrom = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Application").Range("F3")` when you already declared your worksheet. `Target.Range("F3")` would have done exactly the same thing. But kudos to you - at least you reference your worksheets unlike most people here.

Comment: `LastRow2 = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row` your code doesn't populate the 4th column (only the first 3), so this won't increment each time you copy a row...